# How to Register Interests using 'ALL_KEYS' in Spring Data GemFire with ClientRegionFactoryBean

Tags: spring-data-gemfire

I am going to register interests in **ALL_KEYS** for my Pivotal GemFire client via *Spring Data GemFire*, but I find that `ClientRegionFactoryBean` has one method.

`org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.ClientRegionFactoryBean.setInterests(Interest<MyRegionPojo>[] interests)`

In this case, I only can set the exact keys, but I want to register interests for all keys. My key is not a simple class like String, or Long, but a complex object **MyRegionPojo**.

Please help if any method to implement so like GemFire API `region.registerInterest("ALL_KEYS");`

Comment: You should definitely add some more details, including code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You problem statement is a bit vague but I assume/suspect you are configuring your *Spring (Data GemFire)* (SDG) application using [*Spring* JavaConfig](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java)?

However, I will quickly add that this is not unlike how you would register interests in all keys using SDG's XML namespace, as shown [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap:region:client:interests).

The JavaConfig approach is similar, but clearly based on "strongly-typed arguments", namely 1 or more sub-type instances of the [`o.s.d.g.client.Interest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/client/Interest.html) class to the [`o.s.d.g.client.ClientRegionFactoryBean.setInterests(:Interest<K>[])`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/client/ClientRegionFactoryBean.html#setInterests-org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.Interest:A-) method.

By way of example, you might do the following...

```
@Bean("Example")
public ClientRegionFactoryBean<?, ?> exampleRegion(GemFireCache gemfireCache) {

  ClientRegionFactoryBean<MyRegionKey, MyRegionValue> exampleRegion = 
      new ClientRegionFactoryBean<>();

  RegexInterest regexInterest = new RegexInterest();

  regexInterest.setKey(".*");

  exampleRegion.setCache(gemfireCache);
  exampleRegion.setShortcut(ClientRegionShortcut.PROXY);
  exampleRegion.setInterests(new Interest[] { regexInterest });
  exampleRegion.setKeyConstraint(MyRegionKey.class);
  exampleRegion.setValueConstraint(MyRegionValue.class);

  return exampleRegion;
}
```

**NOTE: updated the example above to reflect the proper way to register (Regex) interests based on SDG 1.9 or earlier.  Keep in mind that the `o.s.d.g.client.RegexInterest.getRegex() [delegates to getKey()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/1.9.11.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/client/RegexInterest.java#L41-L43) therefore you can set the Regular Expression using setKey(:String) as I have shown above.**

Notice the [`o.s.d.g.client.RegexInterest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/client/RegexInterest.html) sub-type registration, which is effectively the same as register interests in "ALL_KEYS", as described [here](http://gemfire-93-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html#registerInterestRegex-java.lang.String-) as well.

Hope this helps!

-John

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want for java config, but I am facing another issue when using this code, new RegexInterest(".*") tells there is no such construct,
The constructor RegexInterest(String) is undefined.
By the way, what you mean the sub-type registration? thanks for your answer.

Comment: I guess you are using SDG 1.9.x or earlier then? (And hopefully SDG `1.9.11.RELEASE`, now). This is what @rainer meant when you are asking questions; you need to provide this sort of detail.  Anyway, the SDG 1.9.x `o.s.d.g.client.RegexInterest` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/1.9.11.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/client/RegexInterest.html) does not have any parameterized constructors unlike SDG 2.0.x (e.g. 2.0.6.RELEASE), `RegexInterest` only has a default, no-arg constructor in 1.9.  I have no intention of changing this as 1.9 is reaching its EOL.

Comment: By sub-type, I mean in SDG 2.0.x and later has 2 sub-classes of `o.s.d.g.client.Interest` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/client/Interest.html).  There is the `o.s.d.g.client.KeyInterest` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/client/KeyInterest.html) and `o.s.d.g.client.RegexInterest` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/client/RegexInterest.html).